# Oracle IDENTITY column versus PRIMARY KEY

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

Having trouble finding anything definite about whether it's needed to specify that an `IDENTITY` column as `PRIMARY KEY` in Oracle 12.2c.  Does an `IDENTITY` column automatically create an index, like a `PK`? Is it just being redudant?  I do believe you can have an `IDENTITY` column and separate PK, though we are not doing that.

```
ID NUMBER AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY == ID NUMBER AS IDENTITY ?
```

Comment: Using an IDENTITY column as a PK defeats the primary purpose of PK: ensuring each record is unique. By definition each entry in an IDENTITY column is unique. The only time this would make sense is if two completely identical records are valid with in your table.

Comment: @Ethan - The primary purpose of a PK is referential constraint. This is done via a NOT NULL constraint + a unique index on the key. Also, in case you need to link the table to another, you  either need a PK or a unique constraint. IDENTITY columns do not give you all that, so I don't think it defeats the purpose. You can however put "GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY" to force uniqueness to that column, it may or may not allow you to "foreign key" to it ..

Comment: @Ethan - technical (surrogate) primary keys generated as a monotonically incrementing series of numbers are standard in databases through the world. The good practice is to define **unique constraints** over the business keys (candidate keys) which guarantee the logical uniqueness of the record whilst giving us a simpler key to reference in foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does an IDENTITY column automatically create an index, like a PK?

No. An identity column is just a column auto-populated with a sequentially generated number. You can use it however you want, but the typical use is as a synthetic primary key.

> Is it just being redundant?

No.

> I do believe you can have an IDENTITY column and separate PK

Yes, you can.

> though we are not doing that.

Fine, if you mean you are not having a separate PK *column* in addition to the identity column. Defining a PK *constraint* over the identity column would be a good idea.

Comment: *"But you probably should."* I think the OP is saying they do not have an identity column and a separate primary key column, that is they are using the identity column as their primary key. And why not? It's the convention to use a technical (surrogate) key as the primary key and enforce candidate keys (business keys) through unique constraints.  Identity columns are perfect for technical primary keys. So why should the OP not be defining their identity columns as primary keys?

Comment: I took it to mean a PK constraint considered as separate from the underlying column, but your interpretation makes more sense. The OP should define a PK referencing the identity column.

Comment: Fine. But you probably should ... edit your answer to make it clearer ;)

Answer (score 1):

An `IDENTITY` column can be and often is useful as primary key, but it doesn't have to be.

The identity column is very useful for the surrogate primary key column. When you insert a new row into the identity column, Oracle auto-generates and insert a sequential value into the column.

https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-identity-column/

Answer (score 1):

It's a common mistake to mix logical and physical organization of data.

You successfully mixed 3 orthogonal concepts:

- logical:  `PRIMARY KEY` constraint
- physical: `INDEX`
- automatic value generation: `IDENTITY` column

> Does an IDENTITY column automatically create an index, like a PK? Is it just being redudant?

Those questions are very version dependent. `IDENTITY` itself was introduced in Oracle 12.x.

> I do believe you can have an IDENTITY column and separate PK, though we are not doing that.

You are correct here.

Auto value generation, logical constraint and physical data organization are orthogonal to each other.